# TypeScript infer specific property type from object interface

Tags: typescript

Say, I have this interface:

```
interface MyObject {
  all: string[] | {[value: string]: string}
  some: string[]
}
```

In my code I have an object of this type which I deconstruct, and then use one of the properties as a function parameter:

```
const {all, some} = myObject as MyObject

myFunction(all)
```

Now, when I define the function, I'd like to somehow infer the type of `all` from `MyObject` interface. How do I do that?

```
function myFunction(all: ???) { ... }
```

I know I could define my interface like so:

```
type All = string[] | {[value: string]: string}

interface MyObject {
  all: All
  some: string[]
}
```

and then use the `All` type in my function definition, but is it possible to just infer the type of the property from the object interface?

Comment: It's just `MyObject['all']`

Comment: I can't believe it was so easy... . Thanks!